# How do I make my list without brackets, commas, and have every element start on a new line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a loop that creates a list of sentences and I want them to print like this (all on different lines) :

```
Hi my name is joe
Hi my name is Sally
Hi my name is Bert
```

But they are printing like this instead:

`['Hi my name is joe', 'Hi my name is Sally', 'Hi my name is Bert']`

I am not too great at python so I would like a simple answer please. My loop looks a little like this:

```
sentence = "Hi my name is " + random.choice(name)
if name not in list:
        list.append(sentence)
```

Comment: Please post your code and error message.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: There is no error messages, I typed my code in, but it didnt format correctly when I asked my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list is like this:

```
list = ['Hi my name is joe', 'Hi my name is Sally', 'Hi my name is Bert']
```

You would then simply do this:

```
for a in list: print(a)
```

Which would output this:

```
Hi my name is joe
Hi my name is Sally
Hi my name is Bert
```

Comment: That was easy, thank you so much!

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if you feel it is satisfactory - see ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yes, thank you. It was just making me wait a while before I could accept your answer